# Question on Terraform statefile block definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have my terraform state file in AWS s3. say

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
      bucket = "my-bucket-name"
      key = "my-key-name"
      region = "my-region"
  }
}
```

Now, while going over some old code, I see the following block -

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
}
```

What is the meaning of this block without any details of the s3 bucket ? Can anyone please help me understand.

Comment: it will ask you for the credentials when applying

Comment: Yup, there are required parameters and they can be provided on the CLI when running the commands. That is called partial configuration. For example: https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/configuration#partial-configuration.